# php multidimensional array output blank

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i'm trying to output data table with PHP multidimensional array, but i have problem with foreach loop it loops for only one index, it doesn't output next indexes, in my print_r output for $docs

```
Array
(
    [docs] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Rew
                    [imgurl] => http://localhost/site/uploads/2012/07/print.jpg
                    [level_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 3
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Second
                    [imgurl] => http://localhost/site/uploads/2012/07/type.jpg
                    [level_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

in my php

```
$i =0;
foreach ($docs as $doc){
   foreach($doc as $a_doc){
       foreach($doc as $a_doc){

        echo $doc[$i]['title'];         
     }

   }
   $i++;
}
```

but it doesn't give any output,i would REALLY appreciate if someone could give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array containing the `docs` key only has a single element, you can do this:

```
foreach( $docs['docs'] as $doc ) {
    echo $doc['title'];
}
```

If it should have more than one entry (besides `docs`), go for:

```
foreach( $docs as $entry ) {
    foreach( $entry as $doc) {
        echo $doc['title'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($docs as $key => $doc){

    echo $doc['title'];

}
```

Each `$doc` that is iterated is an array of doc attributes. The `$key` in the `foreach()` loop is the currently indexed key for the currently iterated element in the `$docs` array.